# how to get numbers before certain character string

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in sql server which contains a number and a random character or a dash and random character string. I want to split the number part. do u have any suggestion?

**column Value sample**

```
12343Tfc
23435-fdf5g
7667ggjkl
3333gfsdfs6767
```

**expected output**

```
12343
23435
7667
3333
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for the CASE.  We just add a dummy character at the end as a "fail-safe"

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('12343Tfc')
,('23435-fdf5g')
,('7667ggjkl')
,('3333gfsdfs6767')
,('1111')             -- Added
,('AA')               -- Added
,('AA1111')           -- Added
 
Select *
      ,NewValue = left(SomeCol,patindex( '%[^0-9]%', SomeCol+'A')-1)
 from @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol         NewValue
12343Tfc        12343
23435-fdf5g     23435
7667ggjkl       7667
3333gfsdfs6767  3333
1111            1111
AA  
AA1111
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
CAST(CASE WHEN [Column] LIKE '%[^0-9]%' 
   THEN LEFT([Column] ,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',[Column] )-1) 
   ELSE [Column]  END AS INT)
```

This uses a regex to find if the string contains non numeric characters, if so it takes the left numeric part, up to the first non numeric character.
If the string contains only numeric characters, you just use the value.